# How to make Quarkus use local library classes

Tags: maven, quarkus

I'm starting with Quarkus using Maven and can't seem to find a solution to this:
I have a Quarkus app with dependencies on the libraries `A` and `B`. Both are imported as "Modules" (not Maven modules!) in the IntelliJ IDEA project for my app.
When starting Quarkus in dev mode, it ignores the classes in `target/` of `A` and `B` and instead loads them from the Maven repository. Therefore with every change in either `A` or `B`, I have to `mvn install` the respective library, so my Quarkus app uses the correct code.
Coming from Thorntail, this was not necessary. Is there a solution that doesn't require auto-installing `A` and `B` on every build and also makes HotSwap work for those libs?

Edit:
As [@CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) requested, here's a minimal example of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.8.3.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.8.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-universe-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>B</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

`A` and `B` are listed in IntelliJ IDEA under "Project Structure... > Modules > test > Dependencies" as Module Depenencies, not Maven Dependencies. So the code in `A` and `B` should be HotSwappable.

Comment: How do you have the dependencies configured between the modules in Maven? Is there aggregate pom.xml that you import? Do you use SNAPSHOT dependencies? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to understand why the dependencies are not resolved from sources.

Comment: I've updated my original post. I was not talking about Maven modules but IntelliJ IDEA modules, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How exactly do you run it? Using Maven? It appears to be specific to the plug-in which runs the task and how it configures the dependencies. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have a built-in configuration for Quarkus yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228507.

Comment: I'm using this plugin to run it: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14242-quarkus-integration

Comment: It's the same as manually issuing `mvn compile quarkus:dev` in the console or using the UI based approach you linked. All three ways have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the issue is not IDE specific, I've edited the tags.

Comment: Oh yes, right. I didn't think too much about the relevance of the tags when typing them and instead just mentioned everything involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution. As so often: Once you know it, it's trivial.

Open your run configuration, expand the `Environment` dropdown (only populated when an application module is selected) and check the option `Resolve Workspace artifacts`:
[image: Run configuration]